# Completion issues with CaseMilestones

Tags: servicecloud, casemilestone

I am in the process of assessing Entitlement Processes and CaseMilestones.

I have set up an Entitlement Process that has 2 CaseMilestones set up.

- The first called *First Response* is initialised on Case creation.
- The second called *Transferred* is initialised on setting the Case *Status* to a certain value.

*The Entitlement Process is set to exit on case close.*

I have notices that the *Transferred* milestone will disappear from the Case Milestones related list when the case is closed, whereas the *First Response* milestone will not. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

In addition, the completion dates of the milestones are not being set when the case is closed. It was my understanding that all milestones would be marked as complete when the Entitlement Process exited. I have checked that the Entitlement Process is indeed exiting on close and this is the case. Does anyone know why the milestones are not getting completed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled with this myself for a while before coming to the realization that CaseMiletones that are not yet completed (or violated) will be deleted by the system when the criteria they use is no longer valid.

However if they are completed (or violated) they will never be deleted by the system, and in fact cannot be deleted manually (even from apex running as system).

It sounds like your Transferred milestone is not completed when the case is closed, and the status change to closed makes it no longer valid for the case, so the system automatically deletes it.

I do not believe completion dates on milestones are ever automatically populated. I've created apex triggers that handle the population of them when their criteria are completed, but that of course requires a familiarity with apex triggers in order to be viable.

Comment: This answer has a mistake (I Think).
"However if they are completed (or violated) they will never be deleted by the system, and in fact cannot be deleted manually (even from apex running as system)." => Remove violated. Because, if the milestone gets violated, if the entry criteria is not met anymore, the system will remove it.

Comment: @atef please feel free to directly edit the answer. It's been long enough since I worked with entitlements that your take is likely more accurate